# Server to Server HTTP Authentication

Tags: tls, http-basic-auth

I'm designing an API, and had some quick questions about HTTP authentication and security.

The API will involve two web servers, one of which I am the developer of (let's call it Server 1). The server that I am interested to retrieve data from, unfortunately, is one I do not have control over (Server 2).

In order to retrieve data from Server 2, a 'user' needs to log in first. This is performed with basic HTTP authentication.

My question is: Are there any serious security vulnerabilities present if I send a username and password (contained in JSON) in the body of a POST request from Server 1 to Server 2 in order to log a 'user' in and create a session? The username and password would be safely contained in config variables until they are sent in the POST request. Both servers use SSL, so the messages should be encrypted.

As I do not have control over Server 2, this is the only way I can think of to create this API, without requesting development on Server 2.

I would think this is basically the same as using a regular HTML form to log in to a service using username/password, but I wanted to get confirmation from the community.

Thank you very much.

Comment: For basic HTTP authentication, the authentication credentials are sent in the headers o the HTTP request, not the body.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication.  If that's the case, and it's over https, then this is a very common method of authentication.  Many REST API's work this way.  Sessions are not needed, you simply send the credentials in the header of every request.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the Header convention, but I wasn't sure of how important it is. Does it make any difference to security?

Comment: Possibly, but it's not clear from your question whether server 2 relies on basic HTTP authenticaton (as you mention in the third paragraph) or of server 2 relies on sessions for authentication (as you mention in the fourth paragraph).  Normally, if a server relies basic HTTP authentication, there is no need for sessions.

Comment: I'll attempt to include the password in the header and see if that works. What I've had to do so far in testing is send a JSON request, with the user and pw info, to the endpoint that the login form goes to. I include a cookie in the header of this, and subsequent, requests, in order to maintain a session. This works for me. Does this method present security issues?